# Adjusting scroll view depending on content size of subview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to allow the scroll view to adjust size depending on the size of a subview on this page. All of the other constraints for the objects in the picture work fine.

[image: Imgur]

When I add constraints to my subview to hug to the left, right, and bottom of the screen (and the top of the subview hugs to the bottom of the segmented control) and then update frames, it makes the height of the subview 0.

[image: Imgur]

I can't add a height constraint to the subview because the size of the subview will change dynamically depending on the amount of content in it, which will then change the size of the scroll view.

How can I accomplish this without adding a height constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view hierarchy should look like :

[image: view hierarchy]

> Create a single child view of the UIScrollView where we will put all
>   of our content
>
> The content view has to be an explicit size (or a placeholder size in
>   interface builder and set at run time). In other words your content
>   view cannot depend on the scroll view to get its size.  It can,
>   however, depend on views outside of the scroll view to get its size.

From Apple *Technical Note TN2154*

- > Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO on all views
  >   involved.
- > Position and size your scroll view with constraints external
  >    to the scroll view.
- > Use constraints to lay out the subviews within the
  >   scroll view, being sure that the constraints tie to all four edges of
  >   the scroll view and do not rely on the scroll view to get their size.

  [UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

  [Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

Comment: I apologize, but I'm confused by your answer. Why wouldn't I be able to tie the subview to the left right and bottom of the scroll view and tie the top of the subview to the bottom of the segmented control? My hierarchy is structured like you said as well. The scroll view has constraints to all four corners of the view. If I tie the top of the subview to the top of the scroll view, the subview will move everything depending on the screen size

Comment: Can you share your your view hierarchy and the constraints of your scroll view and the content view, basically what you need is 1) Scroll view 0 to all edge 2) content view with an explicit width and height (it may be calculated based of the views inside the content view) Autolayout  can automatically calculate the content size if you set up your constraints the right way

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to understand what you're saying now, but I think I just don't understand why Xcode would make it so that I needed another view on top of the scroll view, seeing that the scroll view itself should act as some type of content container. How do I make the content view height change based on the views inside the content?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `Equl Heights` & `Equal Width` constraints to your Subview.

[image: Equal Width & Equal Heights]